# iText7 C# SvgConverter unicode character is not displaying

Tags: c#, svg, itext7

I'm trying insert svg image to pdf using iText7. My image contains language specific characters like Ą in unicode `&#x0104;` but it's not displays in pdf file. If I'm open svg file with browser or any editor everything is ok.
my svg is:

```
<svg width="450" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <metadata id="metadata5">image/svg+xml</metadata>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <g stroke="null" id="layer1">
   <text stroke="null" transform="matrix(2.650662232016657,0,0,2.670811106880592,-0.5802407909153997,-0.5590199871829791) " xml:space="preserve" x="3.50000" y="31.68476" id="text3" stroke-width="0.26458" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="8px" font-weight="normal" font-style="normal">
    <tspan stroke="null" id="tspan3" x="3.09517" y="31.68476" stroke-width="0.26458" font-size="8px">&#x0104;</tspan>
   </text>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

my code is:

```
string svg = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\tmp\svg.svg");
string pdf = @"c:\tmp\test.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
PdfSigner stamper = new PdfSigner(reader, ms, new StampingProperties());
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.GetSignatureAppearance();
appearance.SetPageRect(new Rectangle(10, 600, 200, 100));
var xx = SvgConverter.ConvertToXObject(svg_logo, stamper.GetDocument());
new PdfCanvas(appearance.GetLayer0(), stamper.GetDocument()).AddXObjectFittedIntoRectangle(xx,new Rectangle(200,100));
}
```

What I am missing?
Have tried  different fonts with no luck.

Comment: What happens if you just try to display normal text?  I found one example on internet where there is a space after the 'x'.  Not sure if that will make a differrence.

Comment: With normal text everything ok. Have tried convert text to curves, but iText dont display it properly. Space after x breaks svg.

Comment: Then maybe it is a font issue.  The font that you are using doesn't support the characters.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font and https://www.adobe.com/products/type/opentype.html

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

```
string svg = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\tmp\svg.svg");
string pdf = @"c:\tmp\test.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfSigner stamper = new PdfSigner(reader, ms, new StampingProperties());
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.GetSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.SetPageRect(new Rectangle(10, 600, 200, 100));
    SvgConverterProperties svgConverterProperties = new SvgConverterProperties() ;
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.CreateFont() ;
    FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
    fontProvider.AddFont(fontProgram, "windows-1257");
    svgConverterProperties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
    var xx = SvgConverter.ConvertToXObject(svg_logo, stamper.GetDocument(),svgConverterProperties);
    new PdfCanvas(appearance.GetLayer0(), stamper.GetDocument()).AddXObjectFittedIntoRectangle(xx,new Rectangle(200,100));
}
```

I had set encoding in SvgConverterProperties.